# Can memcached make full use of multi-core?

Tags: memcached, multicore, parallel-processing

Is memcached capable of making full use of multi-core? Or is there any way tuning this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

memcached is multi-threaded by default and has no problem saturating many cores.  It's a bit harder to saturate all cores on more massively parallel boxes (e.g. a 256-core CMT box) just because it gets harder to get the data in and out of the network.

If you find areas where some sort of contention is preventing you from saturating cores, file a bug or start a discussion.

Answer (score 13):

memcached has "-t" option:

```
       -t <threads>
          Number of threads to use to process incoming requests. This option is only meaningful
          if memcached was compiled with thread support enabled. It is typically not useful  to
          set  this higher than the number of CPU cores on the memcached server. The default is
          4.
```

so, I believe it can use all your CPU cores, of course if it was compiled with corresponding option.

Answer (score 4):

Based on a [this](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/enhancing-the-scalability-of-memcached-0) research by Intel, Memcached v.1.6 beta cannot scale well on a multicore system. Their experiments show that as core counts increase from 1 to 8, maximum throughput (with a median RTT < 1ms SLA) only doubles.

Answer (score 0):

CAREFUL.  This terminology is quite confusing.  Memcached man page says -t option is only good up to the number of cores.  However, this is odd because threads and processes are VERY different.  Threads have NOTHING to do with the number of cores.  Processes can definitely run on more than one cor, while threads cannot (unless they call to an OS routine, then they can thread switch and pack in more than 100% cpu usage).  Threads share memory and just depend on an instruction pointer to differentiate who is who.  Processes share nothing unless it is explicitly declared as shared ahead of time, and sharing occurs via the OS.

Overall, I want MORE CLARITY from the Memcached people about whether their app is multiprocessing or multithreaded and thus if it can use more than 100% of cpu.

Comment: [Threads have NOTHING to do with the number of cores]

The reason why its says to set your number of threads to the number of cores is that you generally want to have one core executing a given thread. Any more than that then the cpu will have to context switch between threads which impacts performance in vary degrees depending on what you're trying to do